# How to delete a variable string in file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

Actually I am using

```
sed -e s/Perro-A//g -i *-a.log
```

to delete the string Perro-A from many files ending with *-a.log.

But sometimes in the files I might not have Perro-A; I might have strings like Perro-B, Perro-C, Perro-14, Perro-X , Perro-DHFN, etc.

I need to update the previous command to delete any string starting with "Perro". How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you just wanted to delete all string starting with "Perro", you can use:

```
sed 's/Perro[^ ]*//g' *-a.log
```

If you want to edit the file in place, you can use `-i` option with `sed`, like

```
sed -i sed 's/Perro[^ ]*//g' *-a.log
```

**Update**

If you don't want to have multiple spaces, you can use:

```
sed -i sed 's/Perro[^ ]*//g' *-a.log | tr -s " "
```

sample data,

```
rahul@rahul: cat a.log
Foo Perro-B Perro-C Bar
Perro-14 cmd  Perro-X
Perro-DHFN abc xyz
aBcD Perro-14

rahul@rahul: sed 's/Perro[^ ]*//g' a.log | tr -s " "
Foo Bar
 cmd
 abc xyz
aBcD
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only a few characters away from your own answer:

```
sed -i -e 's/Perro.*//g' *-a.log
```

(I moved the `-i` earlier just to make it obvious to the reader early on that we're doing in-place edits). This will delete any string that *contains* the string "Perro", followed by any (or no) amount of characters (`.*`).

If, instead, you want to remove strings that *start* with "Perro", then you just need to anchor the string with `^`:

```
sed -i -e 's/^Perro.*//g' *-a.log
```

Lambert makes a good clarifying point in the comments here; the above sed statements remove the strings from the line, but keep (the possibly-blank now) line. If, instead, you want sed to delete the line if it contains Perro, then he's got the right syntax:

```
sed -i -e '/Perro/d' *-a.log
```

... or similarly, delete the line if it *starts* with Perro:

```
sed -i -e '/^Perro/d' *-a.log
```

Comment: Not entirely, it just removes Perro from the lines. To delete the lines entirely use `sed -i -e '/Perro/d' *-a.log`

Comment: @Lambert I guess OP wanna delete only string starting with `Perro`

Comment: Yes, the question in only to delete the string not the line, but cool

Comment: @alloppp did my `sed` operation helped you ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, You mention 'remove' ("This will remove any line that contains the string "Perro") and 'delete' ("If, instead, you want to delete lines..." in your answer which may be rephrased?

Comment: Thanks, Lambert -- not enough caffeine yet apparently!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the word Perro-* to the next whitespace for example you can use:

```
sed -ie 's/Perro-.*\s//g' *-a.log
```

Sample:

```
cat /tmp/foo
Prefix Perro-A Suffix
Pre Perro-B Suf

sed -ie 's/Perro-.*\s//g' /tmp/foo

cat /tmp/foo
Prefix Suffix
Pre Suf
```

Note that sed does not handle non-greedy filtering.

Another way is to use `perl` for the job:

```
cat /tmp/foo
Prefix Perro-A c Perro-B Suffix
Perro-C Pre Suf Perro-D

perl -i -pe 's/Perro-.*?\s//g' /tmp/foo

cat /tmp/foo
Prefix c Suffix
Pre Suf
```

Comment: ASAIK this won't work when multiple string exist on single line.